# Finding number of deleted rows by a query

Tags: java, mysql, sql-delete

Earlier I had 2000 records.

After I fired below query, I would be having 1500 records.

```
DELETE FROM logInfo WHERE datediff(now(), whatTime) >= 2
```

Is there any query which would tell me how many records are deleted by above records?

I know I can use below query before delete command, however I am just curious is there any other way to find after deletion.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM logInfo WHERE datediff(now(), whatTime) >= 2
```

**I need this in JAVA or MYSQL.**

I know in php it would be `mysql_affected_rows()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [preparedStatement.executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) returns the number of affected rows.

Comment: I am so lazy... I printed int value, but didnt't even looked once :D :P             totalDeleted = psmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("totalDeleted====" + totalDeleted);

Answer (score 2):

When you execute query, return for this query would be how many rows effected (boolean value). Which is nothing but how many rows deleted.

`DELETE FROM logInfo WHERE datediff(now(), whatTime) >= 2`

Comment: I am so lazy... I printed int value, but didnt't even looked once :D :P             totalDeleted = psmt.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("totalDeleted====" + totalDeleted);